# JMeter JUnit SpringRunner issue

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, jmeter

My JUnit tests were defined like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring-test.xml" })
public abstract class MyTest {
```

It works perfectly well when tests are running normally via maven, etc.
But, when I tried to run it using JMeter, seems like it is no longer setting spring dependencies defined in the xml file, looks like this RunWith annotaion is ignored. I'm getting NPE when trying to use spring injected deps. 
Is there a solution how to solve it properly ?

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit Sampler implementation is not using the standard JUnit Runner facility.
See point 7 in the documentation (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request).

Also read the discussion in this ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47888#c1.

If your are interested in the implementation have a look at [`org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/junit/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JUnitSampler.java).

Comment: > Apache JMeter is a 100% pure Java desktop application designed to load test client/server software (such as a web application ).
(see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/intro.html)

If this is not your scenario, then JMeter is not the right tool.

Did you consider using Ant/Maven to trigger your Unit-Tests?

Comment: I wanted to integrate jmeter with maven and jenkins, so that we could have continuous performance metrics of some important integration tests we run with jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get the same thing working since a few days.
Problem with annotations though.
It ran in jmeter without using the annotations, like loading the context using:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
context.getBean("helloWorld");
```

Comment: Yeah, I also did that as a workaround, but this is very annoying.

Comment: True. @RunWith is part of Junit(using 4.11) in Jmeter jar. It not being able to pick up SpringJUnit4ClassRunner inspite of having spring-test under lib of jmeter is befuddling.

Comment: I've lot of existing test cases that use annotations;so this workaround is not going to cut it.

Comment: All my tests extends from an abstract one, which has this annotation. So I needed to change it just in one place ;)